# Call function in another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Hello I'm facing this problem:

I created a button in class Luncher, when I click it I want to call a function in another class (Main) but I dont have a result.
However when i define (Main) class in run mode I get the intended result. What is the problem ?

This work for me : 
[When i set Main.class in run mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf3cr.png)

And this not work :/ :
[When i click in button to show Main.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLHSg.png)

This is the code for the runable class (Luncher):

```
public class Luncher extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Luncher() {

    setSize(600,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton1.setText("CLIC ON ME !");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Main example = new Main();
            example.doThis();
        }
    });

       GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane()); 
       getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(147, 147, 147)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(180, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(108, 108, 108)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(169, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );


}


public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Luncher().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
} }
```

And the second class is Main:

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private static GUI gameGui = new GUI(); //GUI its a JFrame class 
private static CardLayout card = new CardLayout();
private static JPanel content = new JPanel();

    public Main(){
       doThis();

    }


public static void doThis (){
    content.setLayout(card);
    gameGui.setVisible(true); 
    gameGui.add(content);
    gameGui.repaint();
    gameGui.revalidate();
    card.show(content);
    }


public static void main (String [] args) {


}  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few basic solutions available to you.

## You could...

Pass a reference of `Main` to `Luncher`.  This way, when you want to, you can just call the functionality of `Main` you need to.

This is not the best solution, as it couples `Launcher` to `Main`, making it difficult to re-use the code and possibly exposing functionality (of `Main`) to `Launcher`, which `Launcher` should have access to.

## You could...

You could use a delegate or observer pattern...

Define an `interface` (or contract) which `Launcher` requires delegates to implement in order to perform the functionality it requires.

```
public interface LauncherDelegate {
    //...
}
```

You would then have `Main` implement this `interface`

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame implements LauncherDelegate {
    //...
```

and pass a reference of itself to `Launcher`

```
public class Luncher extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private LauncherDelegate delegate;
    public Luncher(LauncherDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate
        //...
```

This way, `Launcher` can only call the functionality described in the contract, it decouples the code, as any implementation of `LauncherDelegate` can be used and `Launcher` won't care, making the code more re-usable and configurable.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I did apply the second method but what i write in  public void run() {  new Luncher(*HERE*).setVisible(true); }

Comment: Same problem - you need an instance of the delegate

Comment: instance of the delegate ? When I went down `CardLayout card = new CardLayout(); ` in the function I got the result what do you think? @MadProgrammer

Comment: [history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10361242/halas) has me [concerned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

Comment: @Halas Based on your previous questions, you seem to be not understanding the basic concept of [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yep 